# Checking exit code of last command using "if" statement

Tags: powershell

I want to check the status of last command and based on the exit code, the commands will be executed further.

The last command execute was:

```
$hiveJob = Start-AzureHDInsightJob -Cluster $clusterName -JobDefinition  $hiveJobDefinition
Wait-AzureHDInsightJob -Job $hiveJob -WaitTimeoutInSeconds 5400
Get-AzureHDInsightJobOutput -Cluster $clusterName -JobId $hiveJob.JobId -StandardOutput
```

The output is:

```
Cluster         : crmhdinsight  
ExitCode        : 0  
Name            : Hive: show tables;  
PercentComplete :   
Query           : show tables;  
State           : Completed  
StatusDirectory : 7dc4b67f-99a9-4c6b-a9f3-ffe8b4e29c7e  
SubmissionTime  : 7/28/2014 11:44:04  
AMJobId         : job_1406103802152_0053
```

Now, I want to execute further commands only if the exitcode is zero. How do I write an `if` statement for this condition?

Answer (score 64):

You're talking about "exit code". If you mean `$LastExitCode` [automatic variable](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html), it is only populated when you call windows program, RAR for example:

```
$x=rar
$LastExitCode
```

It will return exit code 7 (if you have RAR installed).

cmdlets, however, don't fill this variable. You can use another automatic variable `$?` for this:

```
$x=gci
$?
```

It only gives `$True` if command completed successfully or `$False` if there was an error.

Answer (score 6):

From Get-Help about_If:

Syntax
   The following example shows the If statement syntax:

```
   if (<test1>)
       {<statement list 1>}
   [elseif (<test2>)
       {<statement list 2>}]
   [else
       {<statement list 3>}]
```

Note: the square brackets around the elseif and else indicate they are optional.

Assign your returned object to a variable:

```
$hiveJob = Start-AzureHDInsightJob -Cluster $clusterName -JobDefinition  $hiveJobDefinition
Wait-AzureHDInsightJob -Job $hiveJob -WaitTimeoutInSeconds 5400
$Result = Get-AzureHDInsightJobOutput -Cluster $clusterName -JobId $hiveJob.JobId -StandardOutput
```

Then

```
if ($Result.ExitCode -eq 0)
  {
    #More commands
  }
```