# How do a catch an error from dotNet.exe command line

Tags: powershell, .net-core

I have a powershell script that calls dotNet.exe to publish (and also restore).  I need powershell to return an error if dotNet.exe has an error.

How do I detect and error from dotNet.exe?

Comment: You'll want to examine the exit code from dotNet.exe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994595/checking-exit-code-of-last-command-using-if-statement