# Get return code from "second" Powershell process

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to execute a powershell in a cmd.
`powershell.exe -noprofile -command "&{ start-process -FilePath 'powershell.exe' -ArgumentList '-noprofile get-service' -verb RunAs}"`

This executes a powershell.exe and a powershell.exe again as an admin.
What I want is the errorcode from the "second" powershell.exe and NOT from the "first".

Comment: Why not return second exit code to the first instance and then first instance will return it to the original caller?

Comment: How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Add `-Wait` parameter to your `start-process` call and then exit with `$LastExitCode`

Comment: The errorcode is stored in %errorlevel% after this cmd ?

Comment: If you're calling this command line from cmd.exe then yes it will be in errorlevel.

Comment: I always get "0" as errorcode. Because "start-process" was successful. But I want the errorcode, if for example "get-service" doesn't work.

Comment: `get-service` is not a process, it doesn't have an exit code per se. I believe you  need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994595/checking-exit-code-of-last-command-using-if-statement)