# Docker Healthcheck not running powershell commands?

Tags: powershell, docker, health-check

I am working with Docker and I have created a Dockerfile which converts my dotnet application into an image. I can then run this image and everything is working fine.
I am using **mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS base.**

Now, I wanted to add the 'HealthCheck' feature of Docker. In that HealthCheck, I want to use some Powershell logic, but from the moment I use Powershell, de HealthCheck gets classified as unhealthy.

For example:

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD powershell -command exit 0
```

Results in an unhealthy container.

For example:

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD exit 0
```

Results in a healthy container

Any powershell logic I try to insert, which either returns or exits a 0, give me unhealthy containers. Right now, I'm thinking that it is the powershell just erroring whatever the logic is.

Anyone can hint at what I am doing wrong to get some powershell code login inside my Docker Healthcheck?
I need this powershell code within the HealthCheck for a specific reason which is not really important.

Thanks

---

EDIT:
I have also tried:

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD powershell -command return 0
```

and

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD powershell -command Write-Host 0
```

Both with the same result: an unhealthy container.

Comment: Can you check what the exit code is when you run that powershell command normally?

Comment: If I run 'exit 0' in my powershell window, it just closes my powershell window. According to the docs of Docker Healthcheck tell me:

"The command’s exit status indicates the health status of the container. The possible values are:

0: success - the container is healthy and ready for use
1: unhealthy - the container is not working correctly
2: reserved - do not use this exit code
"

So that is why I'm trying it like this.

Comment: Could you create a script with that command in it, run it, and check the exit code? Sorry, I'm not familiar with PowerShell; I mostly write Bash.

Comment: I can surely do that, not so familiar myself. But what exactly do you mean with 'check the exit code'?

Just run the dedicated script and see what it does?

Comment: `But what exactly do you mean with 'check the exit code'?` Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994595/checking-exit-code-of-last-command-using-if-statement/24995041

Comment: When running the ps1 file with 'exit 0' inside, and then retrieve the $LastExitCode, I get printed a 0. When running the ps1 file with 'exit 1' inside, and then retrieve the $LastExitCode, I get printed a 1. So I see no reason why this should not work in Docker Healthcheck..

Answer (score 1):

We use the following command in AWS ECS

```
powershell -c 'try { if ((iwr -Uri http://localhost:${CONTAINER_PORT}${HEALTHCHECK_PATH} -UseBasicParsing -DisableKeepAlive).StatusCode -eq 200) {return 0} return 1; } catch { return 1 }'
```

We are running windows 2016 and 20H2 containers